# RavenDB query index with custom fields names

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb

I have collection of documents Message in RavenDB. 
Definition:

```
class Message
{
    string Content;
    Tag[] Tags;
}

class Tag
{
    string Value;
}
```

And i have index:

```
from doc in docs.Messages
from docTagsItem in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)doc.Tags
select new { Content = doc.Content, TagsValue = docTagsItem.Value }
```

Here we have field with name TagsValue which isn't part of class Message, that's why i can't using

```
Session.Query<Message>(indexName).Where(m=>m.TagsValue==tagValue)
```

How should query this index from .NET by TagValue? Should i use Advanced.LuceneQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use Linq you need to create a type with that property to query that, or you can use Lucene API.

Note that you don't actually need to make a query like that using a static index, you can do that using just dynamic indexes and pure linq.