# Ravendb trying to query child object results in "cannot index not indexed field"

Tags: ravendb

I think the class will be self explanatory based on the index:

```
public class CalendarMatchIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<CalendarMatch>
    {

        public CalendarMatchIndex()
        {
            Map = matches => from match in matches
                select new
                {
                     match.CalendarId,
                     match.MatchDate,
                     match.CommunityId,
                     CategoryId = match.ImportData.CategoryId,
                     TeamTypeId = match.ImportData.TeamTypeId,
                     TeamSheetDeadline =match.ImportData.TeamSheetDeadline,
                     ActivityId =match.ImportData.ActivityId,

                };
        }
    }
}
```

Query:

```
var query = session.Query<CalendarMatch, CalendarMatchIndex>()
.Where(x => x.ImportData.CategoryId == input.CategoryId);
```

Results in the 'importdata.categoryid not indexed error'.  How do i query this field without resorting to using a separate result class and having to store all fields?

edit: adding Json:

```
{
    "CalendarId": "7ui824avw496",

    "ImportData": {
        "ActivityType": "Tournament",
        "ActivityId": "aqhfl52xbff137",
        "LinkedMatchId": "bykdzj5j11kagf"
    },
    "CommunityId": null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a result class in the past (ravendb 2.5) i used this syntax on the map:

```
Map = matches => from match in matches
                select new
                {
                     match.CalendarId,
                     match.MatchDate,
                     match.CommunityId,
                     ImportData_CategoryId = match.ImportData.CategoryId,
                     ImportData_TeamTypeId = match.ImportData.TeamTypeId,
                     ImportData_TeamSheetDeadline = match.ImportData.TeamSheetDeadline,
                     ImportData_ActivityId = match.ImportData.ActivityId,

                };
```

with this map your query should works:

```
var query = session.Query<CalendarMatch, CalendarMatchIndex>()
    .Where(x => x.ImportData.CategoryId == input.CategoryId);
```

Comment: This worked and you have made me a very happy person with this answer. It means I can save a huge amount of storage with all the unnecessary index storage I've been forced to do. thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your index definition, you index `ImportData.CategoryId` as `CategoryId` field and this means your query should looks like this:

```
var query = session.Query<CalendarMatch, CalendarMatchIndex>()
.Where(x => x.CategoryId == input.CategoryId);
```

See `x.ImportData.CategoryId` -> `x.CategoryId`  change in my query.

Comment: No, it doesn't work and results in a red squiggly line. It's because the object queried relates to 'CalendarMatch' class which doesn't have a definition for categoryId, only 'importdata.categoryid'

Comment: Should work as you are run query agains index mentions, where 'CategoryId = match.ImportData.CategoryId' ... so CategoryId is top level field in index resultset. Can you share you JSON item example?

Comment: Added deprecated json item. As you can see, some of the fields are not populated as for example categoryId is a new field I have added and this is an older json item. Could the fact that it doesn't exist yet be the reason I get errors?

Comment: here is link to screenshot of query and error.https://imgur.com/a/bdYu8Os

Comment: I see ... its probably this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411671/ravendb-query-index-with-custom-fields-names ... add CategoryId  field to your class so C# can see it and query it as Where(x => x.CategoryId == input.CategoryId) ... this CategoryId value exists in index resultset as defined. You can try it in Studio usin RQL.

Comment: Yes, in studio it sees the categoryId field.  I'm afraid I didn't uderstand that answer in the link. In the end I've gone down the sad route of having to use a result class and store all fields. I can't seem to get any indexes to work properly without storeallfields. I have a long way to go until I understand these things properly. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Create a result class with structure corresponding to the index results:

```
public class CalendarMatchResult
{
    public string CalendarId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MatchDate { get; set; }
    public string CommunityId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string TeamTypeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TeamSheetDeadline { get; set; }
    public string ActivityId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can query the index like this:

```
var query = session.Query<CalendarMatchResult, CalendarMatchIndex>()
    .Where(x => x.CategoryId == input.CategoryId);
```

You don't need to store the fields unless you need to retrieve them directly for the index. For filtering, fields which are not stored are just fine.